# Is there any way to send a message to telegram bot with clicked on inline keyboard?

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I have a reply markup keyboard. and I set a user_id for it's callback data. is there any way to send a text message to that id which set in callback data when press the button?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried some code?

Comment: I don't know how to tried some code for my problem and send some text after hits on my inline keyboard.

Comment: Please explain your idea for bot in more detail. Maybe there's a more simple way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... and I set a user_id for it's callback data

You don't need to set `user_id` as a `callback_data` for button of your `InlineKeyboard`.

When user hits a button, you will receive an [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) containing user's id: `update.callback_query.from.id`

> is there any way to send a text message to that id which set in callback data when press the button?

Given user's id, bot can send a message using method [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage). Pass user's id as `chat_id` parameter.

---

> when a user hits an inline keyboard , user redirects to that url which is set in url of the inline keyboard and I add user's score in my data base.this is why I need url and call back data together.I have that url and the user score in my data base.and when user click on inline keyboard I want to add url's counter and user's counte

Technically you can't put a URL **and** a `callback_data` in `InlineKeyboardButton`. From [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton):

> InlineKeyboardButton. This object represents one button of an inline keyboard. You **must use exactly one** of the optional fields.

So bot won't be able to know whether user pressed button with URL or not.

The only possible workaround I see here is to use another web server as a "proxy". Here's my idea:

1. Bot sends an `InlineKeyboard` to user. Keyboard contains buttons with URLs leading to your website like `https://example.com?url=<URL_ID>&user=<TELEGRAM_USER_ID>`
2. `URL_ID` here is destination site or its id/hash, `TELEGRAM_USER_ID` is telegram user's id or its hash
3. You web server increments the counter in your database and redirects user to destination site.

Comment: Thanks. I know about sendMessage. But I want to send text to my telegram bot when I press on my inline keyboard. How to send a text when I hits on inline keyboard?  And I have another question.Is there any way to use callback data and url together for an inline keyboard?

Comment: 1. Why will user need an `InlineKeyboard` to send text? Bot can handle text messages without any type of keyboard. 2. You probably don't need it. You should tell more about your bot and I'll try to suggest a solution.

Comment: for number 2, I want this: when a user hits an inline keyboard , user redirects to that url which is set in url of the inline keyboard and I add user's score in my data base.this is why I need url and call back data together.I have that url and the user score in my data base.and when user click on inline keyboard I want to add url's counter and user's counter.